# Cómo se implementa la privacidad en las clases de ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2015

En una clase en ES6, al igual que ocurre con los objetos, tanto sus atributos, como propiedades, son públicos. Entonces **cómo se hace para aislar ciertas propiedades y métodos para evitar que puedan ser modificadas de forma externa?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Actualización

A partir de [ecma262](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-functions-and-classes.html#sec-runtime-semantics-methoddefinitionevaluation) se pueden crear propiedades y métodos privados usando el prefijo `#`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
class Persona {

  #saludo = 'Hola'; // propiedad privada
  
  #loggear(mensaje) { // metodo privado
    console.log(mensaje);
  }
  
  constructor(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre; // propiedad publica
  }
  saludar() { // metodo publico
    this.#loggear(this.#saludo + ' ' + this.nombre + '!');
  }
}

let p = new Persona('Marcos');
p.saludar();
console.log(p.saludar);
console.log(p.loggear);
console.log(p.nombre);
console.log(p.loggear);
```

---

## Solución desactualizada

La respuesta directa es no, no se puede.

Pero! Usando `IIFE` se puede simular.
Así por ejemplo:

```js
let Persona = (function () {
  let saludo = 'Hola'; // propiedad privada
  
  function loggear(mensaje) { // metodo privado
    console.log(mensaje);
  }

  class Persona {
    constructor(nombre) {
      this.nombre = nombre; // propiedad publica
    }
    saludar() { // metodo publico
      loggear(saludo + ' ' + this.nombre + '!');
    }
  }

  return Persona;
})();

let p = new Persona('Marcos');
p.saludar();
console.log(p.saludar);
console.log(p.loggear);
console.log(p.nombre);
console.log(p.loggear);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias marcos por la respuesta, es un metodo diferente para realizar dicha tarea, revisa este metodo tambien es aplicable: http://www.etnassoft.com/2016/12/02/introduccion-a-la-poo-en-javascript-moderno-las-nuevas-clases-en-es6/

Answer (score 1):

En este momento para el ES6 no hay una manera definida para generar propiedades y métodos privados.

Sera agregado en un futuro:

[puedes checar en developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Palabras_Reservadas)

Comment: Gracias jorge, ya he tenido la oportunidad de leer algunas cosas en la web y he encontrado que se puede con weakmap. Aqui te dejo la documentación para que la revises :https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/WeakMap o leas el siguiente articulo donde encontre la respuesta http://www.etnassoft.com/2016/12/02/introduccion-a-la-poo-en-javascript-moderno-las-nuevas-clases-en-es6/

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de hacer privados los miembros internos de un objeto, es escribiendo en su declaracion, la palabra var delante. Ejemplo:

```
function Myclass() {

    metodoPublico = function() {

    };

    var atributoPrivado = 14;

}
```

El elemento `atributoPrivado` no puede ser accedido desde fuera.

Comment: Gracias isaac por la respuesta, pero la pregunta va encaminada a ES6, y las nuevas clases y constructores implementados en dicho estandar