# Definir tipo de variable y evitar usarla directamente en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo una clase Avión y se le puede agregar la cantidad de pasajeros, para ello cree un método set, la cosa es que creí que esto evitaba que se pueda usar la variable directamente, ya que tenia un getter y un setter.

Y el problema es que se puede hacer esto: `avion.pasajeros = "Azúcar";` por lo menos con el setter podía comprobar si es un numero y tirar error.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

```
class Avion {

    constructor(marca, pasajeros) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.pasajeros = pasajeros;
    }

    encender() {
        console.log("El avión esta encendido.");
    }

    apagar() {
        console.log("El avión esta apagado.")
    }

    set setPasajeros(cantidad) {
        this.pasajeros = cantidad;
    }

    get getPasajeros() {
        return this.pasajeros;
    }

}

avion = new Avion("Acme", 50);

avion.setPasajeros = avion.getPasajeros + 10;
avion.pasajeros = avion.pasajeros + 10;
avion.pasajeros = "Azúcar";

console.log(avion.getPasajeros);
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo se implementa la privacidad en las clases de ES6?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38664/c%c3%b3mo-se-implementa-la-privacidad-en-las-clases-de-es6)

Comment: @Marcos Realmente se puede seguir sobreescribiendo la propiedad con cualquier valor, así que no es realmente útil esa respuesta

Comment: Lamentablemente javascript no es un lenguaje fuertemente tipado. Eso quiere decir que una variable puede cambiar en toda la ejecucion. Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una validacion para que cuando agreguen un valor no numerio asigne por defecto algun valor que creas conveniente.

Comment: @DavElsanto En las nuevas versiones de Javascript es posible definir elementos privados con el operador #

Comment: No lo sabia muchas gracias. Pero el comentario no cambia que la variable va a poder seguir cambiando de valores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías modificar un poco tus getters y setters para hacer parecer que estás accediendo directamente a la propiedad. Sin embargo, debido a que JS no fue inicialmente pensado para ser usado en POO será muy fácil acceder a la propiedad que estás tratando de "ocultar" ya que finalmente las clases no son más que "[funciones especiales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#definiendo_clases)" que devuelven un objeto.

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
class Avion {
  /**
   * Clase Avion
   * @param {string} marca Marca del avión
   * @param {number} pasajeros Número de pasajeros
   */
  constructor(marca, pasajeros) {
    this._marca = marca;
    if (typeof pasajeros !== 'number') {
      throw new TypeError('pasajeros debe ser de tipo number')
    }
    this._pasajeros = pasajeros;
  }

  set pasajeros(pasajeros) {
    if (typeof pasajeros !== 'number') {
      throw new TypeError('`pasajeros` debe ser de tipo number')
    }
    this._pasajeros = pasajeros;
  }

  get pasajeros() {
    return this._pasajeros;
  }
}

avion = new Avion("Acme", 50);

avion.pasajeros = avion.pasajeros + 10;
avion.pasajeros = avion.pasajeros + 10;
avion.pasajeros = "hola";

console.log(avion.pasajeros);
```

Lo anterior implementa un mecanismo que valida el tipo de dato de `_pasajeros` a través de `pasajeros` usando un setter. Sin embargo como mencioné al principio, al ser un objeto, fácilmente se podría acceder a la propiedad `_pasajeros` y saltar esa validación.

```js
class Avion {
  /**
   * Clase Avion
   * @param {string} marca Marca del avión
   * @param {number} pasajeros Número de pasajeros
   */
  constructor(marca, pasajeros) {
    this._marca = marca;
    if (typeof pasajeros !== 'number') {
      throw new TypeError('pasajeros debe ser de tipo number')
    }
    this._pasajeros = pasajeros;
  }

  set pasajeros(pasajeros) {
    if (typeof pasajeros !== 'number') {
      throw new TypeError('`pasajeros` debe ser de tipo number')
    }
    this._pasajeros = pasajeros;
  }

  get pasajeros() {
    return this._pasajeros;
  }
}

avion = new Avion("Acme", 50);

avion.pasajeros = avion.pasajeros + 10;
avion.pasajeros = avion.pasajeros + 10;
avion._pasajeros = "Azúcar";

console.log(avion.pasajeros);
```

Si bien es cierto que TypeScript puede ofrecer mecanismos para hacer esto al momento del desarrollo, lo cierto es que al ser transpilado caerías en lo mismo (mira [este playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYYl2W), en la sección .JS) en tiempo de ejecución.

Otra opción (un poco compleja pero más efectiva) podría ser la encapsulación a través de [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```js
const Avion = function (pasajeros) {
  if (typeof pasajeros !== 'number') {
    throw new TypeError('`pasajeros` debe ser un número.');
  }
  return (function () {
    let _pasajeros = pasajeros;
    return {
      setPasajeros: function (pasajeros) {
        if (typeof pasajeros !== 'number') {
          throw new TypeError('`pasajeros` debe ser un número.');
        }
        else {
          _pasajeros = pasajeros;
        }
      },
      getPasajeros: function () {
        return _pasajeros;
      }
    };
  }());
}

const test = new Avion(5);
// const test = new Avion("Azúcar"); // Esto lanzará error

console.log('Pasajeros al momento del constructor:', test.getPasajeros());
test.setPasajeros(10);
// test.setPasajeros("Azúcar"); // Esto lanzará error
test._pasajeros = 1000;
test.pasajeros = 1000;
console.log('Pasajeros después de la actualización:', test.getPasajeros());
// Nota como en lugar de actualizar los valores dentro del closure, actualizas los del objeto "padre"
console.log(test);
```

Podrías aprovechar el uso los [campos privados](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) a través de `#` como mencionan otros compañeros. <s>Sin embargo debes de tener en cuenta que esto sigue en [fase experimental](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields#development-history) y pudiera desaparecer en un futuro</s>. Al parecer ya está en [Fase 4](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/pull/332) y será [publicado próximamente](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md).

Referencia: [Encapsulation in Javascript](https://www.intertech.com/encapsulation-in-javascript/) (en inglés).

Answer (score 2):

En las nuevas versiones de Javascript esto es posible utilizando un nuevo operador, sin embargo tienes que tener en cuenta que al hacer bundle y generar una versión que sea compatible con múltiples navegadores y sistemas puede que la versión de código generada no soporte este operador, por eso debes usarlo con cuidado teniendo en cuenta estas limitaciones

**Referencia**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Ejemplo:

```js
class A {
  #nombre = 'Javascript';
  
  logName() {
    console.log(this.#nombre);
  }
}

const a = new A();

// console.log(a.#nombre); No es posible
a.logName(); // Posible
```